# Select Subreport to View

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, subreport

I have created a a report with 5 subreports in it.  What I would like to do, but cannot figure out how, is to create a parameter that lets the user choose which subreport they would like to view.  There is no data in the main report, just in the subreports.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a parameter and add the subreport choices in the values field. If you want the user to be able to choose multiple reports, make sure to set the parameter to accept multiple values.
Then you can either create multiple detail sections and suppress each section depending on the parameter value(s) or right-click on the subreport, click "Format Subreport" and do a conditional suppression on the subreports depending on the value(s) of the parameter.
The formula could look something like:

```
{?parameter} <> "subreportName" OR
not({?parameter} in ["subreportName1", "subreportName2", etc..]) = True
```

Or you can do an on-demand subreport that only runs when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create 5 sections in the report. You can do this by going to the section expert and selecting the report header and click insert button 5 times. You'll end up with report header a to e.
2. Add each of the subreport in each sections that you created.
3. Create a string parameter, give it a name like `Myparam`, and add 5 values in the Value section. For example: `report1`, `report2`, `report3`, `report4`, `report5`. Change the options to Allow Multiple Values to True.
4. In the section expert, select report header a, and in the formula in suppress (No Drilldown), add this formula.

   > > not("report1" in {?Myparam})
5. Add for each section. the formula changes according to The report name changes as you go through each of the sections. eg. for section b you formula would change to:

   > > not("report2" in {?Myparam})
6. Drag the parameter on the report. Suppress it if you don't want it visible. Test the report. The formula should work for selection one report, or multiple reports.